# A confusion about function name lookup

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution, name-lookup

I'm confused by some rules in the standard.  I'll cite them here:

#### [[basic.lookup.argdep]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.argdep#3):

> Let X be the lookup set produced by **unqualified lookup** and let Y be the lookup set produced by argument dependent lookup (defined as follows).

So the sentence above means that the set X is created by **unqualified lookup**.  Then we look at the rules of **unqualified lookup**:

#### [[basic.lookup.unqual]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.unqual#1):

> In all the cases listed in [basic.lookup.unqual], the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories; **name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name**.

The emphasized part "name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name" means that once a name is found, the lookup stops.

So my question is:

```cpp
void func(int){}
void func(double){}
int main(){
  func(0);
}
```

Consider the above code.  The name of `fun` is used in an unqualified way.  So the unqualified lookup rules are performed.  Hence, once either `func(double)` or `func(int)` is found, the lookup is stopped.  So, why can `func` be overloaded, i.e. the set of candidate function contains both `func(int)` and `func(double)`?  Doesn't it contradict the unqualified lookup rules?  If I miss something, please correct me.

Comment: `0` is an integer value. Why is there ambiguity here? Compare with `func(0.0)`.

Comment: @tadman I do not talk about overload resolution here,I just say the name lookup,according to the **unqualified lookup**

Comment: I'm just responding to your code example where you're not using it in an unqualified way. Maybe you mean `func(int i = 0)` and `func(double i = 0.0)` where `func()` is unqualified? I'm not sure from your specific question, the wording is a bit hazy.

Comment: @tadman why do you think the `func(0)` in my example  is not used by an unqualified way?

Comment: `The lookup for an unqualified name used as the postfix-expression of a function call is described in [basic.lookup.argdep].`

Comment: @super But,the rules in [basic.lookup.argdep] refere to **unqualified lookup**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reasonable question. The relevant part is "the scopes are searched for a declaration **in the order listed**".

In pseudo-code

```
for (auto scope: scopes)
{
   if (scope.contains(name))
      return scope;
}
throw ill_formed(name);
```

As soon as one scope is found that contains `name`, that scope is selected. Further scopes on the list are not searched. Even if `name` occurs in that scope, it will not participate in overload resolution.

In your example however, the selected scope contains not one but two declarations of `func` so overload resolution still happens.

Comment: A wonderful answers.Do you mean that these order lists are for scopes?So,if it like this,how to interpret that a name of varible exists more than one in the same scope?how to hide the name before one?thanks

Comment: Correct; the compiler first makes an ordered list of candidate scopes, and then it goes through the scopes one by one until it finds a scope which contains _at least_ one declaration of the name. Of course, a _variable_ name can occur at most once in a scope. Only functions have overloading.

Comment: Thanks,I have got it

Comment: In addition,Does the remain of [basic.lookup.unqual] describle what these candiate scopes are?For example,"A name used in global scope, outside of any function, class or user-declared namespace, shall be declared before its use in global scope.",It means that the "candiate scope" of such name is the global scope before where the name used,Right?